# ObjectStore Bluemix connection java

Tags: java, frameworks, ibm-cloud, object-storage

I am tring to connect to the the Object Storage service in Bluemix. However, I keep getting an exception. Here is my code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
     SwiftApi swiftApi;

     String endpoint   = "https://identity.open.softlayer.com/v2.0";
     String tenantName = "object_storage_aedba606_1c69_4a54_b12c_2cecxxxxxx";
     String userName   = "e8ee36a1fa38432abcxxxxxxx";
     String password   = "Y6R(cY3xxxxxxxx";
     String identity = tenantName+":"+userName;
     String provider = "openstack-swift";
     String region = "dallas";
      Properties overrides=new Properties();
         overrides.setProperty(Constants.PROPERTY_LOGGER_WIRE_LOG_SENSITIVE_INFO, "true");
     swiftApi = ContextBuilder.newBuilder(provider)
             .endpoint(endpoint)
             .credentials(identity, password)
             .overrides(overrides)
             .buildApi(SwiftApi.class);

     System.out.println("List Containers");

     ContainerApi containerApi = swiftApi.getContainerApi(region);
     Set<Container> containers = containerApi.list().toSet();

     System.out.println("Listing Containers: ");

     for (Container container : containers) {
         System.out.println("  " + container);
     }
     System.out.println(" ");
 }
```

I keep getting the following exception:

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.jclouds.rest.AuthorizationException: request: 
 POST https://identity.open.softlayer.com/v2.0/tokens HTTP/1.1  [Sensitive data in payload, 
 use PROPERTY_LOGGER_WIRE_LOG_SENSITIVE_INFO override to enable logging this data.] 
 failed with response: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
     at org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.handlers.SwiftErrorHandler.handleError
 (SwiftErrorHandler.java:52)
     at org.jclouds.http.handlers.DelegatingErrorHandler.handleError
 (DelegatingErrorHandler.java:65)
     at org.jclouds.http.internal.BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.shouldContinue
 (BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.java:136)
```

My application is a standalone Java application. I am using the credentials that are supplied within my Object Storage service from Bluemix.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This blog will help you connect to Object Storage in Bluemix https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/connecting-to-ibm-object-storage-for-bluemix-with-java/

You can also access Object Storage using the Swift CLI https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/ObjectStorage/objectstorge_usingobjectstorage.html#using-swift-cli

Comment: Thanks, I ended up dropping the jclouds implementation and using the OpenStack4J instead, as mentioned in the answer above. it is a shame, but the only way I could get things to work. Thanks again